# appium python - how to dump details of an element?

Tags: appium-android, python-appium

StackOverflow friends,

I'd like to find a programmatical way to dump a selected element in Appium Python.

The current solution from StackOverflow is to use

```
element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

but this only works in WebView Context. Nowadays most apps run in NativeApp context, therefore, the 'outerHTML' isn't available.

I saw Appium Inspector can display the selected element's detail,

[image]

I'd like to mimic this in Python, and print out to terminal.

I could have dumped the whole page using

```
driver.page_source
```

but I'd like to use the element-only dump to assert that I have selected the correct element.

By the way, I am testing on Android 13 device.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. driver.page_source returns an xml parsed string
2. read xml into a json object.
3. find your element in json and return subjson